# Writing simple Spark DataFrame into MongoDB in nested structure?

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working in pyspark and I want to save simple dataframes in nested JSON like structure into MongoDB. The dataframe has schema like:

```
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Contact number: int (nullable = true)
```

I used the `DataFrameWriter` API's write method to save the dataframe in JSON format and I used mongo-spark-connector package:

```
output_df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").save();
```

This is pretty straightforward. I get the MongoDB output for every row in the data frame like:

```
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 24,
    "City": "Melbourne"
    "Contact number": 123456
}
{
    "Name": "Wauldron",
    "Age": 49,
    "City": "LA"
    "Contact number": 987654
}
```

They are separate documents. However, I want to save them in a nested structure like:

```
"Personal Details": [{
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 24,
    "City": "Melbourne"
    "Contact number": 123456
},
{
    "Name": "Wauldron",
    "Age": 49,
    "City": "LA"
    "Contact number": 987654
}]
```

I couldn't get this to work. Help me with this.

Comment: follow the [steps](https://github.com/Stratio/spark-mongodb/blob/master/doc/src/site/sphinx/First_Steps.rst#python-api) to connect to DB with proper authentication. Then try the step.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? i have the exact same problem

Comment: Is there any workaround ?